# How to give more weight-age to specific keywords while searching for similar text using elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using elasticsearch to get relevant blog articles from a database of articles. I want results that contain particular words to be given higher score than the search results who do not have them.

I have tried adding stop words and given more to other fields but the results are not quite as expected. I am using developer mode of the Kibana interface of elasticsearch

"""

```
GET blog-desc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["Meta description","Title^5", 
            "Short title^0.5"],
            "like" : "Harry had a silver wand he likes to play with! Among his friends he has the most expensive one. The only difference between his wand and his sister's is that in the color",
            "min_term_freq" : 1,
            "max_query_terms" : 12, 
            "minimum_should_match": "30%", 
            "stop_words": ["difference", "play", "among"]
            , "boost_terms": 1
        }
    }
}
```

"""
In the sample code above, I would want search results having "silver" as a word in them given more score than other articles who do not that word.

Comment: Why your fields name contain space i.e "Meta description" ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam the code still works even with spaces.